# ND gives expression instead of number

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, numerics

I have a function `sol` defined as a solution to an equation (computed numerically). Specifically

```
sol[p_, a_] := NSolve[g[p, x, a] == 0, x, Reals][[1, 1, 2]]
```

Trying it out

```
sol[.2, .51]
sol[.2, .52]
sol[.2, .53]
```

gives .51, .52, .53 -- on this range it behaves like identity. Now I try

```
ND[sol[.2, aa], aa, .51 ]
```

and instead of giving me 1 as I would expect, it gives me very long expression involving variable x. I am not using the variable `aa` anywhere else in the code. And yes, I have done `` Needs["NumericalCalculus`"] ``.

How is this possible? It seems obvious to me that it has to return a number! How can it return anything else?

---

Edit: here is the whole code (I have simplified it a little bit, so the values are different than above, but it should still give numbers, not expressions)

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]
g[  x_, a_] = D[RealAbs[1 - x]^1.2 + RealAbs[a - x]^1.2, x];
sol[a_] := NSolve[g[ x, a] == 0, x, Reals][[1, 1, 2]];
ND[sol[aa], aa, .55]
```

Comment: Without knowing `g`, `NDSolve` can not evaluate. And  `Part [[1,1,2]]` simply picks out `x` from the unevaluated `NDSolve`. Therefore, as long as` x` has no value you get: `x`

Comment: I have updated the code. Sorry, I did not include g because I did not think it is relevant. I think the code should now give a number but it gives a very long expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that ND expects an expression. When I gave it sol[aa], it looked at

```
NSolve[-((1.2` (aa - xa))/RealAbs[aa - xa]^0.8`) - (1.2` (1 - xa))/  RealAbs[1 - xa]^0.8` == 0, xa, Reals]
```

then it took the 1,1,2'th element of this which was

```
-((1.2 (aa-xa))/RealAbs[aa-xa]^0.8)
```

which clearly cannot be numerically differentiated.

I have resolved this by making my own little function for numerical differentiation.

Answer (score 1):

After typing your code into a fresh notebook and evaluating it. I get the following results:

I suggest Quitting your Kernel and evaluating everything again. You could also try clearing some variables using `Clear[sol, sol, aa, g, p, x, a]`. And running your code again once you have cleared them.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I did not include g. I have now updated the question to include the definition of g.

Comment: @user2316602 It looks like you are passing an expression in terms of $x$ and $aa$ to `ND`. Try evaluating `sol[aa]`. And let me know if you understand?

Comment: Oh, I see where it went wrong! Thank you

Comment: By the way, how did you create the cool animation?

Comment: The animation is a screen recording converted into a GIF file :) Search "GIF screen recorder" if you are interested in doing this your self. I'm on Ubuntu, so I'm using [this one](https://github.com/phw/peek)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plot of your function:

```
Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, .5, 0.6}]
```

[image]

Why do you think the partial derivatives should be one?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's not one. But it's a number for sure!

Comment: `g` has 2 variables, you only specify one, therefore, what you get is a function of `x`